# Limits without using L'Hospital's rule, $\lim _{x\to -1}\frac{ e ^{x^2-1}-1}{\ln(-x)}$

Tags: calculus, limits, limits-without-lhopital

I would like to calculate these limits without using L'Hospital:

$$\lim _{x\to -1}\frac{ e ^{x^2-1}-1}{\ln(-x)}$$

$$\lim _{x\to 0}\frac{ ({\ln(1-x^2)}+1)^{(1/4)} -1}{x\sin2x}$$

In the second I tried to multiply by $$ {\ln(1-x^2)}+1)^{(1/4)} +1$$ but I think it worth nothing because I need to "vanish" the 0 in the denominator.

Any hints, please?

Comment: For the first limit, $x $ is negative?

Comment: @Bernard
I confused, edit was done

Answer (score 1):

**A Path**

For the first one, you might want to recall these two fundamental limits:
$$\frac{e^{\alpha(x)}-1}{\alpha(x)}\to 1,$$
and
$$\frac{\log (1+\alpha(x))}{\alpha(x)}\to 1$$
when $$\alpha(x) \to 0.$$
Therefore 
\begin{eqnarray}
\mathcal L_1 &=& \lim_{x\to -1} \frac{e^{x^2-1}-1}{\log (-x)}=\\
&=&\lim_{x\to -1}\underbrace{\frac{e^{x^2-1}-1}{x^2-1}}_{\to 1}\cdot \underbrace{\frac{-x-1}{\log (1+(-x-1))}}_{\to 1}\cdot \frac{x^2-1}{-x-1}.
\end{eqnarray}
Can you proceed from here?

For the second problem, I would use the other fundamental limits
$$\frac{(1+\alpha(x))^k-1}{\alpha(x)}\to k$$
and, of course
$$\frac{\sin \alpha(x)}{\alpha(x)} \to 1,$$
again for $\alpha(x) \to 0$. Can you do it this way?

Answer (score 1):

**Hints:**

1.
$$\frac{e^{x^2-1}-1}{\log(-x)}=\frac{e^{x^2-1}-1}{x^2-1}\frac{(x+1)(x-1)}{\log(-x)}=\frac{e^{x^2-1}-1}{x^2-1}\frac{e^{\log(-x)}-1}{\log(-x)}(1-x)\to1\cdot1\cdot2.$$

2.

Notice that
$$\sqrt[4]{a+1}-1=\frac{(a+1)-1}{(a+1)^{3/4}+(a+1)^{2/4}+(a+1)^{1/4}+1}.$$

If $a$ tends to $0$, the denominator tends to $4$.

Then

$$\frac{\log(1-x^2)}{x\sin 2x}=\frac12\frac{\log(1-x^2)}{x^2}\frac{2x}{\sin 2x}=-\frac12\left(\frac{e^{\log(1-x^2)}-1}{\log(1-x^2)}\right)^{-1}\frac{2x}{\sin 2x}\to-\frac12\cdot1^{-1}\cdot1.$$

Make sure that in the expressions of the form $\frac{e^t-1}t$, $t$ does tend to $0$.

Answer (score 0):

Set $\frac{1}{4}=n$:

$$\lim _{x\to 0}\frac{\left(\ln\left(1-x^{2}\right)+1\right)^{\frac{1}{4}}-1}{x\sin\left(2x\right)}$$$$=\lim _{x\to 0}\frac{\color{blue}{\left(\ln\left(1-x^{2}\right)+1\right)^{\frac{1}{4}}-1}}{1}\cdot\frac{{1}}{x\sin\left(2x\right)}$$$$=\lim _{x\to 0}\frac{1}{\color{blue}{\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\left(\ln\left(1-x^{2}\right)+1\right)^{\left(\frac{k}{n}\right)}}}\cdot\frac{\color{blue}{\ln\left(1-x^{2}\right)}}{-x^{2}}\cdot\frac{-\color{green}{2}x}{\sin\left(2x\right)}\cdot\frac{1}{\color{green}{2}}=-\frac{1}{8}$$

The other one has been answered by another users.

Comment: There are several mistakes in the last step @user715522 , typos and a mistake regarding the quotient. Looks like the sum is to be taken inverse for your idea to work. (Also you should explain why the 'base' of the power is less than 1).

Comment: The sum with $n$ going form $1$ to $n$ does not have a clear meaning...

Comment: @dfnu, I edited that

Comment: @user715522 I believe it still makes no sense, since the sum should run over integer numbers, but $n$ is a fraction, in your case.

Comment: @well of course using a fraction as an upper limit for the sum notation is not well defined, but we can express the sum and then let $n$ to be $1/4$ , if you think it does not work so how  we can expand something like $(1+x)^{-3}$ , of course one of the ways is to let $-3=n$ and then the result follows

Comment: @user715522 try to expand it explicitly, then. What are the terms of the sum? If you yourself say it's not well defined, how would you expect a reader to follow you?

Comment: @dfnu ,$\left(\ln\left(1-x^{2}\right)+1\right)^{\left(n-1\right)}+...+\left(\ln\left(1-x^{2}\right)+1\right)^{\left(n-n\right)}$ and as $x$ goes to zero the sum goes to $n$ which is $1/4$

Comment: This is not an explicit expansion. Can you write the terms for $n=1/4$? How many of them are there?

Comment: @dfnu, of course if I let $n=1/4$ directly then it does not work, but we can compute it assuming we have $n$ and what holds for $n$ will also hold for $1/4$

Comment: you really think so?? if "if does not work", how can you explain the step you propose, then?

Comment: I strongly suggest you temporarlily remove the answer and rethink a little bit about your approach to the OP.

Comment: @dfnu, I edited that, now you can put $n$ directly and yes, I had an error, so we have: $$\sum_{k=0}^{4-1}\left(\ln\left(1-x^{2}\right)+1\right)^{\left(\frac{k}{4}\right)}=\left(\ln\left(1-x^{2}\right)+1\right)^{\left(\frac{0}{4}\right)}+...+\left(\ln\left(1-x^{2}\right)+1\right)^{\left(\frac{3}{4}\right)}$$